# Arch Linux: Yaourt/Makepkg Can Not Build Apache

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd, pacman, yaourt

I am using yaourt to automatically compile Apache from source every time there’s an update available from `extra`. I am doing this so that I can have a custom suexec docroot (`/srv/www` rather than the default `/srv/http`). This has worked flawlessly for several updates, until now.

```
$ yaourt -S apache
==> Building apache from sources.

==> Retrieving PKGBUILD and local sources...
receiving file list ... done
./
PKGBUILD
apache.conf.d
apache.install
apache.tmpfiles.conf
apachectl-confd.patch
arch.layout
httpd
httpd.logrotate
pcre_info.patch

sent 199 bytes  received 10416 bytes  7076.67 bytes/sec
total size is 9809  speedup is 0.92
=> removes/replaces '--with-suexec-docroot=\/srv\/http' by '--with-suexec-docroot=\/srv\/www' in global
--- ./PKGBUILD  2012-07-06 00:02:13.000000000 -0400
+++ ./PKGBUILD.custom   2012-07-06 15:49:03.000000000 -0400
@@ -102,7 +102,7 @@
            --enable-so \
            --enable-suexec \
            --with-suexec-caller=http \
-           --with-suexec-docroot=/srv/http \
+           --with-suexec-docroot=/srv/www \
            --with-suexec-logfile=/var/log/httpd/suexec.log \
            --with-suexec-bin=/usr/sbin/suexec \
            --with-suexec-uidmin=99 --with-suexec-gidmin=99 \
==> Edit PKGBUILD ? [y/N] ("A" to abort)
==> ------------------------------------
==> n

==> apache dependencies:
 - openssl (already installed)
 - zlib (already installed)
 - apr-util (already installed)
 - pcre (already installed)


==> Edit apache.install ? [y/N] ("A" to abort)
==> ------------------------------------------
==> n

==> Continue building apache ? [Y/n]
==> --------------------------------
==> 
==> Building and installing package
==> Making package: apache 2.2.22-4 (Thu Jul  5 14:47:33 EDT 2012)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving Sources...
  -> Downloading httpd-2.2.22.tar.bz2...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 5252k  100 5252k    0     0  93231      0  0:00:57  0:00:57 --:--:-- 93283
  -> Downloading httpd-2.2.22.tar.bz2.asc...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   835  100   835    0     0   5191      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10437
  -> Downloading 02-rename-prefork-to-itk.patch...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:06 --:--:--     0curl: (7)     couldn't connect to host
==> ERROR: Failure while downloading 02-rename-prefork-to-itk.patch
    Aborting...
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build apache.
==> Restart building apache ? [y/N]
==> -------------------------------
==>
```

The problem seems to be that curl can’t find `02-rename-prefork-to-itk.patch`. I don’t know what URL that’s located at, in what file it’s specified, or how I might find an alternate location for it. Any idea what is going on/how to troubleshoot?

Comment: See [this thread on the Arch boards](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1125430)...

Comment: @jasonwryan When I try to view the thread I get an error, `Bad request. The link you followed is incorrect or outdated.`.

Comment: My bad: I assumed you were a registered user. Essentially, Apache is outdated, you have to wait until all the modules are built against the newer version (a non-trivial task).

Comment: So, is this unfixable in the interim?

Comment: @jasonwryan It's okay. I actually have an account but I wasn't logged in on this computer. =P

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apache being "outdated". The 2.2 branch will be maintained upstream for a while anyway.

Comment: @PierreCarrier You are right, it is the Arch package that is out of date, not Apache itself.

Comment: No you didn't understand me, the package isn't really outdated. Yes there is a 2.4 branch and it's not packaged in Arch Linux. But 2.2.22 is the latest release of Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.2 is maintained by the Apache Foundation. It's not unreasonable not to jump to Apache 2.4 right away until the ecosystem is reasonably ready, like Arch Linux already did with Python by not jumping on Python 3 right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host where some patches are located is down. But we can change it to another one.

First. Just download the PKGBUILD with yaourt:

```
yaourt -G apache
```

Change the following lines in PKGBUILD:

```
_itkurl=http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/apache2.2-mpm-itk-2.2.17-01
```

To:

```
_itkurl=http://distfiles.alpinelinux.org/distfiles/
```

Also, the patch 03-add-mpm-to-build-system.patch has a different md5, so we fix it. Just change the 4th line in the array "md5sums"

```
'cdfa04985a0efa850976aef01c2a0c40'
```

To:

```
'131408ad4dc7b18547b4e062e7e495ab'
```

The working PKGBUILD is here: http://pastebin.com/iK48xx8f

You can just replace it, if you want. And build apache with:

```
makepkg -i
```

Comment: While the problem had previously seemed to go away, it reappeared after I followed your instructions… which I did modify slightly, using `yaourt -S apache` rather than `makepkg -i`, because I need customizepkg to take effect (or the SuExec docroot would be `/srv/http` rather than `/srv/www`), but I doubt that would have made a difference.

Comment: OK, so, looks like when I did `yaourt -S apache`, that re-downloaded the PKGBUILD, which undid the previous steps. But I don’t know how to get it to not do this.

Comment: Got it to work! Just added your instructions as replace commands to `/etc/customizepkg.d/apache`. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you did! Just as a side note. When you do 'yaourt -G apache' (I mean "-G" not "-S") yaourt downloads the PKGBUILD, patches and install files into a new directory, in our case, named "apache". So you can manually customize any package before you build it. It's useful if you want to have the freedom to tweak the package or just to debug it as I did, for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
curl: (7)     couldn't connect to host
```

According to curl, it couldn't connect to the host. There may be many reasons for this, such as the file not being located on the server. My advice would be to try again later and if that doesn't work then to contact the host where the file is being downloaded from.

Comment: I did notice that, but I don’t know where curl’s trying to get the file from… I should have specified in my question, but I’m looking for how to troubleshoot this with regard to Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, why are you trying to download the `apache` sources from AUR?? `apache` is definitely packaged in Arch.

```
pierre@bar code % pacman -Si apache
Repository     : extra
Name           : apache
Version        : 2.2.22-4
[...]
```

Verify that you have in `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

and at least a few mirrors uncommented in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`, then:

```
# pacman -Sy apache
```

and it should install just fine.

Comment: I’m not. I have a custom build of Apache that yaourt compiles on the fly whenever there’s an upgrade available from extra.

Comment: Would you care to provide more details about it? Sounds like it's broken.

Comment: Modified my post with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

So, I’m not sure if this was due to my recent full system upgrade, or the URL being restored independently of that, but trying again later seemed to get rid of this particular error. However, I still can not build Apache, as I’ve now run into a new error, but that’s a [separate issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43156/cannot-compile-apache-error-ssl-tls-libraries-were-missing-or-unusable).